# Perl MySQL - How do I return a tables last row id without looping through whole table?

Tags: mysql, perl

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id 
                           FROM user 
                          WHERE group == '1' 
                       ORDER BY id DESC 
                          LIMIT 1");
```

I was trying to get the id of the last row in a table without reading the whole table.

I am already accessing via:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name,
                                group 
                           FROM user 
                          WHERE group == '1' 
                          LIMIT $from, $thismany");
$sth->execute();
while(my ($name,$group) = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
```

...and setting up a little pagination query as you can see.

But, I am trying to figure out how to detect when I am on the last (<= 500) rows so I can turn off my "next 500" link.  Everything else is working fine. I figured out how to turn off the "previous 500" link when on first 500 page all by myself!

I thought I would set up a "switch" in the while loop so if ($id = $last_id) I can set the "switches" var.

Like:

```
if ($id = $last_id) {
$lastpage = 1; #the switch
}
```

So I can turn off next 500 link if ($lastpage == 1).
I am really new to this and keep getting stuck on these types of things.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) from tablename` will give you the number of rows, which may or may not be what you need here.

Comment: So I would edit my line to this:  my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select COUNT(*) name,group FROM user WHERE group == '1' LIMIT $from, $thismany");

Comment: I typed that in too fast. That could not work.. I have no Idea what I am doing I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to grab an extra row and see how many rows you really got. Something like this:

```
my @results = ( );
my $total   = 0;
my $sth     = $dbh->prepare(qq{
        SELECT name, group 
        FROM user 
        WHERE group = ?  
        LIMIT ?, ?
});
$sth->execute(1, $from, $thismany + 1);
while(my ($name, $group) = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
        push(@results, [$name, $group]); # Or something more interesting.
        ++$total;
}
$sth->finish();  

my $has_next = 0;
if($total == $thismany + 1) {
    pop(@results);
    $has_next = 1;
}
```

And BTW, please use placeholders in **all** of your SQL, interpolation is fraught with danger.

Comment: Thank you this is helping too.

Comment: I really like this but, I am not totally understanding how to implement. Maybe I am. Please verify. From my understanding, or lack thereof, this returns has_next=1 if there IS another row along with the selected row data popped off the end of the array or has_next=0 if there is no next row and no row data? Am I learning???

Comment: At the end, $has_next should be 1 (true) if there are more results (i.e. if there is data available for another page) and 0 (false) otherwise. Also, the pop() removes the last entry from @result and we just throw it away as we only care if it exists -- the value doesn't matter. So you could "return ($has_next, \@results);" to get the interesting data back to the caller.

Answer (score 3):

Always asking for one more row than you are going to show, as suggested by mu is too short, is a good way.

But if you want to take the other suggested approach of doing two separate queries, one to get the desired rows, and one to get the total count if there had not been a limit clause, MySQL provides an easy way to do that while combining as much of the work as possible:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS name, group FROM user WHERE group = '1' LIMIT ..., ...;
```

then:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

The SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS qualifier changes what a following FOUND_ROWS() returns without requiring you to do a whole separate `SELECT COUNT(*) from user WHERE group = '1'` query.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT COUNT(*) from tablename` will give you the number of rows, so if you keep a running count of how many rows you have read so far, you'll know when you're on the last page of results.

You could generate that query with (untested; away from a good workstation at the moment):

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE group == '1'");
my @data = $sth->fetchrow_array;
my $count = $data->[0];
```

(PS. you should be aware of SQL injection issues -- [see here](http://xkcd.com/327/) for why.)

Comment: BTW, That XKCD Circuit Diagram is GREAT!

Comment: my ( $count ) = $dbh->selectrow_array( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM" . $tablename );

Comment: THANKS EVERYONE! We have comprehension!

Comment: WELL MAYBE NOT! I need the last ID. Not the count. I am stuck again!

Comment: -1: In the general case, assuming that the count of rows is equal to the last row ID is a *huge* assumption to make. If rows have ever been deleted, if the ID was seeded with a starting value other than 1, if ID isn't autoincrement... there are many, many common cases where this assumption will fail.

Answer (score 0):

As Ether mentioned in the comments, pagination usually requires two queries. One to return your paged set, the other to return the total number of records (using a COUNT query).

Knowing the total number of records, your current offset and the number of records in each page is enough data to work out how many pages there are in total and how many before and after the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Although your initial suggestion of `SELECT id FROM table WHERE ... ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` should work for finding the highest matching ID, the standard way of doing this is `SELECT max(id) FROM table WHERE ...`

Comment: max(id) helped a bunch too. You guys are great. I am now learning how to use placeholders as well. Although this is not a public interface, I believe I should learn the most secure method by default. At least at attempt at security using placeholders. Nothing can be "totally" safe from what I have read.